# Ubuntu touch mobil phone browser htaccess not accepted

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I have a big problem. My new bq ubuntu phone browser can't access websites that are protected by htaccess. What can I do?
Thx a lot for any help.
Bye,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do. Basic Auth is not yet supported in the browser. This is [reported as a bug already](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1422534). When it is fixed and an updated image has been pushed out to the image updates server, you will be able to then use the browser to access sites requiring Basic Auth.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to embed the username and password in the URL:

```
http://username:password@domain.tld
```

I think that's possible.

Comment: @A.B. not a real link :-))